# What is the C# equivalence to Linux's signal mechanism?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two threads in my project, say thread A and thread B.

While thread B is busy doing something, I want to send a signal from thread A to thread B. After thread B receives the signal, it executes the corresponding signal handler immediately. In Linux, it is easy to do this with signal. To have the same effect, what should I do with C# threads?

Comment: Do you want to interrupt thread B no matter what it's doing?  Or do you want thread B to check periodically to see if a signal was sent?

Comment: I want to interrupt thread B no matter what it's doing. Otherwise, all the waithandle facilities would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't interrupt a running thread arbitrarily - only threads that are blocking.

Take a look at [this explanation](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Interrupt_and_Abort).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about `signal` in linux, but you can use [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to signal another thread.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be interested in are two methods of the `Monitor` class, though I'm not properly sure they're suited precisely for your needs:

See [Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) and [Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The .Net world uses `WaitHandles` this is an abstract class that exposes methods to allow threads to block until signaled, and exposes methods to signal that the blocking threads should "wake up".

There are a number of concrete implementations, such as `AutoResetEvent`, `ManualResetEvent`, `Mutex`, and `Semaphore`.